# Hashmap in groovy versus Java

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

In Java, if I want to associated one value with an other I would simply do the following:

```
static final Map<String, String> VALUES_BY_NAME;

static {
    final Map<String, String> valuesByName = new HashMap<>();
    valuesByName.put("fruit", "apple");
    valuesByName.put("drink", "Coke");

    VALUES_BY_NAME = Collections.unmodifiableMap(valuesByName);
}
```

And call this Hashmap using the following to return apple for example:

```
VALUES_BY_NAME.get("fruit")
```

Is there something similar with groovy for Jenkins?

Comment: _This exact code_ is valid Groovy code. It's not idiomatic, because semicolons are usually omitted and some syntactic sugar is available for dealing with maps, but it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy you could do

```
def myMap = [fruit: 'apple', drink: 'coke'].asUnmodifiable()
```

Comment: Getting the following error: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.asUnmodifiable() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/1VYf0c) is a running example

Comment: You're probably running an old version of Groovy (pre 2.5).  If you can't upgrade you could create a modifiable map and use `Collections.unmodifiableMap` as before

Answer (score 0):

> I would simply

That isn't simple at all, though. Try this:

```
static final Map<String, String> VALUES_BY_NAME = Map.of(
  "fruit", "apple",
  "drink", "Coke");
```

> Is there something similar with groovy for Jenkins?

Groovy is a different language but uses the same java runtime library under the hood. You can invoke the exact same `Map.of` method from groovy as well.